# How to create modules for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple code:

```
var http = require("http");

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
});

server.listen(8000);

console.log("Server has started.");
```

I would like to put this code into server.js. This code has to be a MODULE that has many internal functions. I would like to create `server` module and `listen()` function inside it.

I should put `createServer()` inside a function called `listen()`.

If I have index.js how can I call this module and then do something like `server.listen()`?

Comment: Question is a bit of a mess. What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 58):

The common pattern for nodejs modules is to create a file (e.g. `mymodule.js`) so:

```
var myFunc = function() {
   ...
};

exports.myFunc = myFunc;
```

If you store this in the directory `node_modules` it can be imported thus:

```
var mymodule = require('mymodule');

mymodule.myFunc(args...);
```

So, in your case, your module `server.js` could look like this:

```
// server.js
var http = require("http");

var listen = function(port) {
    var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
    });
    server.listen(port);
};

exports.listen = listen;
```

which would be invoked:

```
// client.js
var server = require('server');
server.listen(8000);
```

Comment: so in my server.js i can't call "server" variabile....because it's local (inside listen function.....right?

Comment: @dail That's right, I'm afraid.  If you made its declaration module-wide by putting it outside the function you could only create one server.  Your utility functions could be inner functions within `listen`, though, where they'd still have access to that variable.

Comment: Is it possible to import a module that is stored in a specific location on the disk (i. e., `/home/username/Desktop`), instead of in the `node_modules` folder?

Answer (score 5):

Old post, but if someone is still interested in I would suggest following solution:

```
//server.js

var http = require("http");

// As soon as method will be used outside the module, use "this":

this.listen = function(port) {
    var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
    });
    server.listen(port);
};


//index.js

var module = require('./server');
module.listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// main.js
var server = require("server");

server.listen(8000);

console.log("Server has started.");


// server.js

var http = require("http");

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
    });
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
});

module.exports = server;
```

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't expect merely "requiring" a module to actually have side effects (such as instanting a server) in the way this code does.

Comment: @Alnitak I guess it is bad design. It's not actually listening on the server though. It's an acceptable grey area for this specifically but generally it is bad